# Understanding derivatives

Tags: derivatives

I don't know if this is written somewhere else. I've looked all over the internet so apologies if this has already been covered.

I'm doing Year 12 Maths in Australia for what it's worth. In our textbooks the formula to find the derivative of a function is:

If $y = ax^n$ then $\frac {\mathbb d y} {\mathbb d x} = anx^{n-1}$. I can see that this works algebraically, but..

An explanation/formula that I've found on the internet but not in my textbook is in the form: $\frac {f(x+h)-f(x)} h$.

With the latter formula, which we're not taught, I can see visually on a graph and algebraically if I make the difference between two x value an ever smaller difference like 0.000...0001 then it gives a y difference value that very closely approximates the actual tangent at a given point. Hopefully I got that correct.

What I'm hoping to get is an intuitive understanding of why this is the same (I gather not always?) as in the form $\frac {\mathbb d y} {\mathbb d x} (ax^n) = anx^{n-1}$ ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: So in your textbook,the general definition of a derivative is not included? Strange indeed..Have you covered basic limits,continuous functions?

Comment: @JDrinas In year 12, not in university. I don't know about your geographic location, but I'm hardly surprised this is the case.

Comment: @Alex easy Alex..I don't know what year 12 means-I suppose the last class of school? In my"geographic location",in the final pre-Uni class we are being taught integration,complex numbers and the like-as in most parts of the world I think.

Comment: Hint. If you know how to expand $(x+h)^n$ you can use the formula you found on the internet to help with your understanding. If you don't know that expansion in general you can do it for $n=2$ and $n=3$. In fact that's @Joel 's answer below.

Comment: @JDrinas No offense ;) We were also taught that, but never saw the definition of a derivative. Only some "special cases" like $\ln$, $\sin$, $\cos$ etc.

Comment: If you'll forgive the self reference, I once wrote [a post](http://davidlowryduda.com/?p=1259) about some of the major ideas in calculus that you might find instructive.

Comment: @Alex :-) Realy?? I am quite surprised honestly..Here in Greece we are taught the definition,do quite a lot of exercises based on it and even some on the $ε-δ$ limit definition earlier..I will post the last problem of the general exams in Greece that was given yesterday on a separate post to give you an idea and also get some general feedback..

Comment: @JDrinas Yes, unfortunately our curriculae (not even for the main subject students) in math don't include such important things. Class was much more about curve discussion and text problems. As a bonus we had a bit of nonformal introduction to limits, but nowhere near the $\epsilon-\delta$ arguments. More like "insert a very very small number into the calculator"-type limits ^^

Comment: @ Alex Tbh and retrospectively thinking about it,for someone not interested in pursuing a major in Math most of what we were taught could have been substituted with something of a more "applied" nature..Most of my former classmates-and those that really excel in their fields,like doctors,even engineers have forgotten all about $ε-δ$ long ago..

Comment: @Alex Take a look if you don't mind and share your thoughts: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1299713/greek-school-exams-calculus-problem

Answer (score 6):

To understand such formula, it is often helpful to do an example first and then deal with the general case.

Let's take $f(x) = x^2$, an easy function. 
With your formula it is $f'(x) = 2x^{2-1} = 2x$

What you have found is actually
$ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ .

As you can see, divding through $0$ is forbidden. We set in the function and get:

$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{x^2+2xh+h^2-x^2}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \, 2x+h = 2x$, which is exactly what your other formula says, too.

Actually, $ f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0}  \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$ is the ***definition*** of the derivative. All other formula can be deduced starting from this definition.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what your definition of the derivative is. There are two standard definitions given in Calculus: $$f'(x) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ and $$f'(a) = \lim_{a\to x} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}.$$

Let's suppose that $f(x) = x^n$. Then $$x^n - a^n = (x-a)(x^{n-1} + ax^{n-2} + a^2x^{n-3} + \cdots + a^{n-1}).$$

This gives: $$f'(a) = \lim_{x \to a} \frac{x^n - a^n}{x-a} = \lim_{x\to a}\frac{(x-a)(x^{n-1} + ax^{n-2} + a^2x^{n-3} + \cdots + a^{n-1})}{x-a} = $$ $$\lim_{x\to a} x^{n-1} + ax^{n-2} + a^2x^{n-3} + \cdots + a^{n-1}$$

Now notice that since we have eliminated the denominator, we can now simply evaluate the limit of the polynomial remaining by evaluating it at $x=a$. Now each term becomes $a^{n-1}$ and there are $n$ terms. This yields:

$$f'(a) = na^{n-1}.$$

Comment: Hey this is really amazing that you guys have given such thorough answers so quickly, really appreciate. With this answer though, I got a bit lost at the line
Let's suppose that f(x)=xn. Then xn−an=(x−a)(xn−1+axn−2+a2xn−3+⋯+an−1)
That said it's almost midnight here a week before exams so maybe I'm just over tired and it will make sense in the morning. I don't expect you guys to reinvent the wheel for me..

Comment: The line you are confused on is a factorization rule for differences of powers. For instance $x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$ and $x^3-a^3 =(x-a)(x^2 +ax+a^2)$. You can expand out the product to give it a try. I hope you find our answers helpful. We do this mostly as a hobby or for practice, and as long as you demonstrate a bit of effort in framing your question, we are happy to help.

Comment: @mitch Understanding calculus (or any level math really) requires a small amount of "reinventing the wheel" in order to truly "get it". It's just how our brains work.

Answer (score 1):

What your textbook gave you as a derivative is a very special case, namely the derivative of a polynomial. You can actually use the **definition** you found on the internet to *prove* the **formula** $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^n = nx^{n-1}$:

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx} x^n = \lim_{h\to0} \frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}h \\
= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{x^n + nx^{n-1}h + \frac{n(n-1)}2 x^{n-2}h^2 + \ldots + h^n - x^n}h = \lim_{h\to0} nx^{n-1} + h\left(\frac{n(n-1)}2 x^{n-2} + \ldots + h^{n-2}\right) = nx^{n-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

You could check it for yourself if you know the Binomial Theorem.

Just expand $(x+h)^n=x^n+nhx^{n-1}+\text {terms involving higher powers of}  h$. Then cancel the $h$ from the bottom line and let $h\rightarrow0$.

Then you have your result.

Answer (score 0):

the quotient you have is called the difference quotient. it approximates the slope of the curve/tangent line at the point.

just to be specific lets take $$f(x) = x^2$$ and look at the tangent at the point $(1,1).$  first we will look at the difference quotient $$\frac{x^2 - 1^2}{(x-1)}$$ for values of $x$ close to $1.$

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}\hline
x & .9 & .99 & .999 & 1.0 & 1.001&1.01 &1.1\\\hline
\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}&1.9&1.99&1.999&undefined&2.001&2.01&2.1\\
\hline\end{array}$

you can see from the table that the difference quotient approaches the value of $2$ as $x$ approaches $1$ from the left and from the right.

we say that the graph of $y = x^2$ has a slope of $2$ at the point $(1,1)$ or the derivative of $x^2$ at $x=1$ is $2.$

Answer (score 0):

The differential quotient is $\lim_{a\to b}\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

I drop the coefficient here.

*Polynomial divison:*

$(a^n-b^n):(a-b)=a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}\cdot b^1+ a^{n-3}\cdot b^2+...+\cdot a\cdot b^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$

---

Some steps of the polynomial division:

[image]

---

There are n summands.

Inserting $b$ for $a$

${b}^{n-1}+b^{n-2}\cdot b^1+ b^{n-3}\cdot b^2+...+\cdot b\cdot b^{n-2}+b^{n-1}$

This is $n\cdot b^{n-1}=\lim_{a\to b}\frac{a^n-b^n}{a-b}$

For $a=x+h$ and $b=x$ we get

$n\cdot x^{n-1}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x+h)^n-x^n}{h}$

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to approach this from a less formal direction.

Suppose you have $t(x) = k * u(x)$.  $t$ is a function that is another function, $u$, times a constant $k$.  The slope of $t$ is then $k$ times the slope of $u$, right?  Or, $t' = k * u'$.

---

If you have $h(x) = f(x)*g(x)$ what happens to the slope?  Well, we can figure it out formally or we can tell ourselves a little story.

Imagine if $g(x)$ did not vary -- it was equal to a constant $k$.  Then the slope would be the slope of $f(x)$ times the constant $k$.

Now imagine if $f(x)$ did not vary -- it was equal to a constant $m$.  Then the slope would be the slope of $g(x)$ times the constant $m$.

Now they both vary. We end up with the rule $h'(x) = k*f'(x) + m*g'(x)$ where $m=f(x)$ and $k=g(x)$, because as you move a bit to the left of $x$ both components end up moving the result up, each by a different amount.

Once we replace $m$ and $k$ with $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ respectively:

$$h'(x) = g(x)f'(x) + g'(x)f(x)$$
which is the chain rule.

Intuitively, the rule is that the slope at that point is the sum of the slopes of each component.  And each component gets its slope multiplied by the current magnitude of the *other* component.

In a real proof, there are second-order effects that the above glosses over.  A formal proof might show that the second-order effects can be neglected (that they disappear in the limit).

---

Now let us apply this to $f(x) = x^2$.  If $h(x) = x$, then $f(x) = h(x)*h(x)$.

We apply the chain rule: $f'(x) = h(x)h'(x) + h'(x)h(x)$.

If we know that $h'(x) = 1$ (because we know the function $y=x$ has a slope of 1), then we get:

$$f'(x) = x * 1 + 1 * x = 2x$$
We can back up to the chain rule, each of the two $x$s contribute a slope of 1, times the magnitude of the other component (which is $x$).  These are then added together.

We can then look at either $x^3$ or $x^4$.  For $x^4$ this is $x^2 * x^2$, so the derivative is $2x x^2 + 2x x^2 = 4x^3$.  For $x^3$ this is $x * x^2$, so the derivative is $1 * x^2 + x * 2x = 3x^2$.

This pattern continues to infinity -- that the derivative of $x^n$ is $n x^{n-1}$.  There are many ways to prove this, from combinatorial to calculus to induction on the chain rule.

---

The derivative is often defined as a limit.  But the derivative is *actually* a way to approximate a function with a linear one around a particular point.  The $f'(7) = k$ means that close enough to $7$, the function $g(x) = k (x-7)$ is a "good" approximation of $f(x)-f(7)$.

The formalism -- as a limit -- all happened long after people where working with derivatives in the real world.  The formalism put it on solid enough ground that we can work out the places where the intuitive definition is probably going to fall apart, instead of blindly walking over a logical cliff in the middle of a mathematical argument, with little ability to work out where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people have been showing you the proof using the binomial formula, but I'll give it to you in a more general way.

Let $f(x)=x^n$ for *any* $n\neq-1$.

Thus we know $$f(x)=e^{n\ln(x)}$$
Therefore: $$f'(x)=\frac d{dx}e^{n\ln(x)}\\f'(x)=e^{n\ln(x)}\cdot\frac d{dx}n\ln(x)\\f'(x)=x^n\cdot\frac n{x}\\f'(x)=nx^{n-1}$$
Which is a pretty neat trick, if you ask me. If you are confused, note that 
$$\frac d{dx}\ln(x)=\frac1{x}$$